# Why does Emacs Jedi always insert “elif” after I type “else:”?

Tags: python, emacs, emacs-jedi

I have installed “Jedi” mode in Emacs but am finding that it auto-inserts the word `elif` every time I create a new line and then type <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> because the colon character apparently kicks off Jedi’s completion logic with `elif` suggested as the top suggestion, and my pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> apparently selects it. So I always, every time I try to type an `else` clause, have to backspace over the extraneous `elif` before continuing.

Is this problem unique to me? I activate Jedi by closely following the documentation:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)                                        
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                                                   
(setq jedi:get-in-function-call-delay 200)                                      
(setq jedi:tooltip-method nil)
```

You can find my entire `.emacs.d/init.el` under version control on GitHub:

```
https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/dot-emacs
```

The current version of Jedi and its associated tools on my system is:

```
(:emacs-version "24.3.1" :jedi-version "0.2.0alpha2")
((:version "3.4.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar 17 2014, 16:13:08) \n[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]" :file nil :name "sys")
 (:version "0.8.0-final0" :file "/home/brandon/.v/fopnp-py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jedi/__init__.py" :name "jedi")
 (:version "0.0.5" :file "/home/brandon/.v/fopnp-py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/epc/__init__.py" :name "epc")
 (:version "0.0.3" :file "/home/brandon/.v/fopnp-py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sexpdata.py" :name "sexpdata"))
```

I note that the `:` character is bound to the Emacs function `python-indent-electric-colon` but I am not sure how to determine whether that function is somehow setting off Jedi’s completion logic without meaning to.

Comment: And, if I keep typing once the `else:elif` construct is on my screen, it does not get retroactively fixed or corrected or removed. I just have the line `else:elif` in the middle of my Python.

Comment: Is there a newer version of Emacs available for your platform? The `python.el` shipped with my Emacs does not appear to contain a `python-indent-electric-colon` function. I can find it [in the `python.el` GitHub repository](https://github.com/fgallina/python.el/blob/master/python.el#L1056), but the latest revision there is a year old. The GNU Emacs source [does not seem to include that function anymore](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1078). (I am also unable to reproduce your problem on my Emacs.)

Comment: The function `python-indent-electric-colon` is, on Ubuntu 14.04, defined in the file `/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/progmodes/python.el.gz` which belongs to the package `emacs24-el` and it seems to be Emacs’s default mode now for editing Python.

Comment: It slipped my mind earlier, but I am not using the `emacs` package (version 24.3.1) but the `emacs-snapshot` package (version 24.3.50.1). `emacs-snapshot` does not have that function defined. Though even when I install and run the `emacs` version I am not seeing your described behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug with the python-mode: `tab-always-indent` value is true but the behavior is the same that it was before.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indent-Convenience.html

My solution:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (setq-local electric-indent-chars (remq ?: electric-indent-chars))
    )
)
```